# Instagram /explore/tags/hollywood/?__a=1 API return HTML response

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, instagram-api

When i call **https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hollywood/?__a=1** using python it always return HTML response like **(Please wait a few minutes before you try again.
)** insted of JSON response. after two days also i got same HTML response. is any possible solution to solve this ?
 Here i attached 
sample code:

```
from requests import request
response = request('GET', 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hollywood/?__a=1')
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be blocked temporarily ,try connecting to a different network, and don't call the script at smaller intervals

Comment: i call it once for every 24 hours but it's not working

Comment: if any other possible way instead of switching network?